# Does a lowdb file database stay in memory with node.js?

Tags: node.js

If I read the [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) database in `file1.js`

```
var users = require('lowdb')('./db.json')('users');

// do something with users
```

when I use it a second time in `file2.js`

```
var settings = require('lowdb')('./db.json')('settings');

// do something with settings
```

does node perform a second read file operation? Or does it get read once after `node index.js` and it stays in memory?

I've always had this question about reading files in node. What I've been doing all this time whenever I want to prevent multiple reading operations (if that's the case in node) is:

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = Foo = {
    init(): function() {
        Foo.bar = fs.readFile('someFile');
    }
};
```

So somewhere in the code (usually `index.js`), I'd `Foo.init()`, and then whenever I need to read the contents, I'd read `Foo.bar`.

Comment: at the risk of sounding snarky, the answer to your first question is "read the lowdb [source](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb/tree/master/src)."  whether or not the .json file gets read from disk multiple times depends on which methods in `Fs` are used by lowdb.  the module could call `Fs.readSync()` every time you invoke it, or it could keep a cache of in-memory files, or it could even just call `Fs.open()` and keep a list of file handles and only lazily read data.  It's not up to node, it's up to lowdb.

Comment: I see. What about the second part? Does that succesfully keep the file "in memory", or am I doing it in vain?

Comment: um, sort of.  [`Fs.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) is asynchronous, so in your code up there, `Foo.bar` will not actually contain the contents of the file.  But using [`Fs.readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options) will return the contents of your file, so yes, that's one way to keep the file's contents in memory.

Comment: And what if I `Foo.bar = require('./db.json')`? Does that achieve the same as using `readFileSync`?